# Use of rate_my_app package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

Could anyone tell me, how you have used rate_my_app https://pub.dev/packages/rate_my_app package in flutter app to increase user reviews?

A sample code will be very useful?

Answer (score 5):

rate_my_app is just a plugin that reminds the users to rate your app. It would increase the positive user's reviews if your app satisfies the user needed.

Example code by [Skyost](https://github.com/Skyost):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rate_my_app/rate_my_app.dart';

/// Main rate my app instance.
RateMyApp _rateMyApp = RateMyApp();

/// First plugin test method.
void main() {
  _rateMyApp.init().then((_) {
    runApp(_RateMyAppTestApp());
    print('Minimum days : ' + _rateMyApp.minDays.toString());
    print('Minimum launches : ' + _rateMyApp.minLaunches.toString());

    print('Base launch : ' + _dateToString(_rateMyApp.baseLaunchDate));
    print('Launches : ' + _rateMyApp.launches.toString());
    print('Do not open again ? ' + (_rateMyApp.doNotOpenAgain ? 'Yes' : 'No'));

    print('Are conditions met ? ' + (_rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
  });
}

/// Returns a formatted date string.
String _dateToString(DateTime date) => date.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + '/' + date.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + '/' + date.year.toString();

/// The main rate my app test widget.
class _RateMyAppTestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Rate my app !'),
          ),
          body: _RateMyAppTestAppBody(),
        ),
      );
}

/// The body of the main rate my app test widget.
class _RateMyAppTestAppBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _RateMyAppTestAppBodyState();
}

/// The body state of the main rate my app test widget.
class _RateMyAppTestAppBodyState extends State<_RateMyAppTestAppBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 40,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            _textCenter('Minimum days : ' + _rateMyApp.minDays.toString()),
            _textCenter('Minimum launches : ' + _rateMyApp.minLaunches.toString()),
            _textCenter('Base launch : ' + _dateToString(_rateMyApp.baseLaunchDate)),
            _textCenter('Launches : ' + _rateMyApp.launches.toString()),
            _textCenter('Do not open again ? ' + (_rateMyApp.doNotOpenAgain ? 'Yes' : 'No')),
            _textCenter('Are conditions met ? ' + (_rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog ? 'Yes' : 'No')),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Launch "Rate my app" dialog'),
                onPressed: () => _rateMyApp.showRateDialog(context).then((v) => setState(() {})),
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Launch "Rate my app" star dialog'),
              onPressed: () => _rateMyApp.showStarRateDialog(context, onRatingChanged: (count) {
                FlatButton cancelButton = FlatButton(
                  child: Text('CANCEL'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _rateMyApp.doNotOpenAgain = true;
                    _rateMyApp.save().then((v) => Navigator.pop(context));
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                );

                if (count == null || count == 0) {
                  return [cancelButton];
                }

                String message = 'You put ' + count.round().toString() + ' star(s). ';
                Color color;
                switch (count.round()) {
                  case 1:
                    message += 'Did this app hurt you physically ?';
                    color = Colors.red;
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    message += 'That\'s not really cool man.';
                    color = Colors.orange;
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    message += 'Well, it\'s average.';
                    color = Colors.yellow;
                    break;
                  case 4:
                    message += 'This is cool, like this app.';
                    color = Colors.lime;
                    break;
                  case 5:
                    message += 'Great ! <3';
                    color = Colors.green;
                    break;
                }

                return [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(message);
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text(message),
                          backgroundColor: color,
                        ),
                      );
                      _rateMyApp.doNotOpenAgain = true;
                      _rateMyApp.save().then((v) => Navigator.pop(context));
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                  cancelButton,
                ];
              }),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Reset'),
              onPressed: () => _rateMyApp.reset().then((v) => setState(() {})),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  /// Returns a centered text.
  Text _textCenter(String content) => Text(
        content,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
}
```

[GitHub code](https://github.com/Skyost/rate_my_app/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:rate_my_app/rate_my_app.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Rating Prompt'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      RateMyApp _rateMyApp = RateMyApp(
        preferencesPrefix: 'rateMyApp_',
        minDays: 3,
        minLaunches: 7,
        remindDays: 2,
        remindLaunches: 5,
        // appStoreIdentifier: '',
        // googlePlayIdentifier: '',
      );

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _rateMyApp.init().then((_) {
          // TODO: Comment out this if statement to test rating dialog (Remember to uncomment)
          // if (_rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog) {
            _rateMyApp.showStarRateDialog(
              context,
              title: 'Enjoying Flutter Rating Prompt?',
              message: 'Please leave a rating!',
              onRatingChanged: (stars) {
                return [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Ok'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (stars != null) {
                        _rateMyApp.doNotOpenAgain = true;
                        _rateMyApp.save().then((v) => Navigator.pop(context));

                        if (stars <= 3) {
                          print('Navigate to Contact Us Screen');
                          // Navigator.push(
                          //   context,
                          //   MaterialPageRoute(
                          //     builder: (_) => ContactUsScreen(),
                          //   ),
                          // );
                        } else if (stars <= 5) {
                          print('Leave a Review Dialog');
                          // showDialog(...);
                        }
                      } else {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ];
              },
              dialogStyle: DialogStyle(
                titleAlign: TextAlign.center,
                messageAlign: TextAlign.center,
                messagePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              ),
              starRatingOptions: StarRatingOptions(),
            );
          // }
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here example for use rate_my_app in screen which called from main

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rate_my_app/rate_my_app.dart';

/// Main Rate my app instance.
RateMyApp _rateMyApp = RateMyApp(
  preferencesPrefix: 'rateMyApp_',
  minDays: 7,
  minLaunches: 10,
  remindDays: 7,
  remindLaunches: 10,
  // appStoreIdentifier: '',
  // googlePlayIdentifier: '',
);

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _rateMyApp.init().then((_) {
      _rateMyApp.conditions.forEach((condition) {
        if (condition is DebuggableCondition) {
          print(condition.valuesAsString());
          // We iterate through our list of conditions and we print all debuggable ones.
        }
      });

      print('Are all conditions met ? ' +
          (_rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog ? 'Yes' : 'No'));

      if (_rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog) _buildShowStarRateDialog(context);
    });
  }

    _buildShowStarRateDialog(BuildContext context) {
    _rateMyApp.showStarRateDialog(context, actionsBuilder: (_, count) {
      final Widget cancelButton = RateMyAppNoButton(
        // We create a custom "Cancel" button using the RateMyAppNoButton class.
        _rateMyApp,
        text: 'CANCEL',
        callback: () => setState(() {}),
      );
      if (count == null || count == 0) {
        // If there is no rating (or a 0 star rating), we only have to return our cancel button.
        return [cancelButton];
      }

      // Otherwise we can do some little more things...
      String message = 'You\'ve put ' + count.round().toString() + ' star(s). ';
      Color color;
      switch (count.round()) {
        case 1:
          message += 'Did this app hurt you physically ?';
          color = Colors.red;
          break;
        case 2:
          message += 'That\'s not really cool man.';
          color = Colors.orange;
          break;
        case 3:
          message += 'Well, it\'s average.';
          color = Colors.yellow;
          break;
        case 4:
          message += 'This is cool, like this app.';
          color = Colors.lime;
          break;
        case 5:
          message += 'Great ! <3';
          color = Colors.green;
          break;
      }

      return [
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () async {
            print(message);
            Toast.show(message, context,
                duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.TOP);

            // This allow to mimic a click on the default "Rate" button and thus update the conditions based on it ("Do not open again" condition for example) :
            await _rateMyApp.callEvent(RateMyAppEventType.rateButtonPressed);
            Navigator.pop<RateMyAppDialogButton>(
                context, RateMyAppDialogButton.rate);

            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
        cancelButton,
      ];
    });

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.